# Running python manage.py runserver returns error LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run python manage.py runserver but i'm getting 
LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'

this is what i get by python manage.py check

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 21, in
>   
>       main()   File "manage.py", line 17, in main
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 357, in execute
>       django.setup()   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line
>   24, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
>   line 114, in populate
>       app_config.import_models()   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py",
>   line 211, in import_models
>       self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in
>   import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 996, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 979, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 968, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 673, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 667, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 222, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager   File
>   "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
>   line 117, in **new**
>       new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py",
>   line 321, in add_to_class
>       value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py",
>   line 204, in contribute_to_class
>       self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())   File
>   "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py",
>   line 28, in **getattr**
>       return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line
>   201, in **getitem**
>       backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line
>   110, in load_backend
>       return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in
>   import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       from .introspection import DatabaseIntrospection            # isort:skip   File
>   "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\introspection.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       import sqlparse   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\sqlparse__init__.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       from sqlparse import filters   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\filters__init__.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       from sqlparse.filters.tokens import KeywordCaseFilter   File "C:\Users\hitma\Envs\ftest\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\filters\tokens.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       class KeywordCaseFilter(_CaseFilter): TypeError: '_TokenType' object is not callable

i followed the main doucment for installing django,Thanks

django version: 2.2

python: 3.6.0a4

Comment: Please show your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting - it should contain `'django.contrib.admin'`. If it's already there, please run `python manage.py check`, and copy the *entire* error message if you get one.

Comment: you have `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)` so you need `admin` in `settings.py`

Comment: i made sure 'django.contrib.admin' is existing in installed apps i did not change any thing in the defualt setting file

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: I edited the question with python manage.py check and the django version

Comment: Please don't use blockquote (`>`) for tracebacks - it means that newlines are not displayed. Use three backticks, e.g. `\`\`\`<traceback goes here>\`\`\``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are facing [this issue in SQLParse](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/issues/286), which led to [this Python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue28214).

I believe the issue will be resolved if you update Python from 3.6 alpha to the latest 3.6.X or 3.7.X release.

Comment: i will try to update the python version and see what i get

Comment: Thanks i updated the python version and it worked ok

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue related to sqlparse. It happens when you are using newest version of packages.
Try : 
**pip install sqlparse**

Note - your terminal must activate virtual environment.

Comment: @Adam I know it is about django. Actually sqlparse is related to django. Both are part of backend development.